# How to integrate the pysolr with tastypie?

Tags: django, solr, tastypie, pysolr

I have created an application, in which i need to take the data from solr instead of database using tastypie, I want to use pysolr for interfacing solar, but i don't know how to integrate the pysolr with the tastypie. Anybody can help me??

Comment: have you had a look at http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/non_orm_data_sources.html there is a full example of all th methods you will need to overridehow to link to non orm datasources